# What variable transformation is used in $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx} {e^x +1}=\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac {dy}{y(y+1)}\quad ? $

Tags: integration

What variable transformation is used in
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx} {e^x +1}=\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac {dy}{y(y+1)}\quad ?
$$

Comment: Have you tried the obvious $y=e^x$ ?

Comment: noticed but wasnt sure about dy

Comment: thanks anyway..

Comment: No problem. Just looking at the integration bounds gives a pretty good guess.

Comment: @KurtG. [and to the OP - i.e. original poster] Elegant, but was not obvious to me.  In fact, absent your comment, my first try, which would probably have failed, would have been to set up the quadratic equation : $~y^2(1) + y(1) - (e^x + 1) = 0,~$ and then *solve* for $~(y)~$ in terms of $x$.  Then, I would have considered the computation as intermediate, rather than final, because I would then have to consider the relationship between $(dx)$ and $(dy)$.  So, it would have been an **iterative** process.  ...see next comment

Comment: +1 to your question, because you have broached a very important and sensitive question.  I went through Volume 1 of Apostol's "Calculus", and nowhere in this book is **any training** given for the strategy that should be used when attacking **general** problems of this nature.  Assuming that your Calculus education is similar, then you encountered **an unfair problem**.

Comment: By the way, I strongly recommend you watch this video on $u$-substitution, since you seem to have some confusion as to how it works. The $\mathrm{d}y$ should not have been any issue to you, but the fact that it was anyway suggests that something is missing in your understanding. Here is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sdYdnpYn-1o

Answer (score 2):

Would it not be nice if the $e^x$ in $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac1{e^x+1}\,\mathrm{d}x$$ was just a simple variable $y$ instead? Then integrating this would be super easy. So why not try that substitution? Let $y=e^x,$ hence $\mathrm{d}y=e^x\,\mathrm{d}x=y\,\mathrm{d}x,$ hence $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac1{e^x+1}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_1^{\infty}\frac1{y+1}\,\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y}=\int_1^{\infty}\frac1{y(y+1)}.$$ Meanwhile, to go backwards, notice that $$\int_1^{\infty}\frac1{y(y+1)}=\int_1^{\infty}\frac1{y+1}\,\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y}=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln(y)}{y+1},$$ in honor of the fact that $$\mathrm{d}\ln(y)=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y},$$ and $$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln(y)}{y+1}=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln(y)}{e^{\ln(y)}+1},$$ so now you can simply let $x=\ln(y).$